# Unused Data in Assembly Needed to Prevent Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, x86

I’m new to Assembly, and I tried to write an echo program.

I’m using Intel-style x86 Assembly.

The following code works perfectly:

```
section .data
  msg db ' '

section .bss
  in: resb 5
    
section .text
  global _start
    
_start:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 2
  mov ecx, in
  mov edx, 5
  int 0x80
    
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, in
  mov edx, 5
  int 0x80 
   
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80
```

However, if I remove the space between the single quotes in `msg` (making it 0 bytes), remove `msg` entirely, or even remove the `.data` section, I get a segmentation fault on execution (before typing any input). Please note that `msg` is not used anywhere in the program.

### My Best Guess

It seems like `msg` is probably preventing the segfault by allocating another byte to the program. That byte is having characters written into it by the read sayscall?

However, increasing the size of `in` and/or decreasing the number of bytes written and read doesn’t fix the issue.

### Commands

I’m using

```
nasm -f elf32 echo.asm
```

and

```
ld echo.o
```

### Research

I have searched for this problem in my favourite search engine and on SO, but to no avail.

I can’t get GDB working on my machine, so I can’t debug the program, unfortunately.

---

Any tips as to why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

---

## Some more information

```
$ uname -m
i686
```

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

It’s Alpine Linux.

```
$ objdump --full-contents good.o

good.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .data:
 0000 20                                                   
Contents of section .text:
 0000 b8030000 00bb0200 0000b900 000000ba  ................
 0010 05000000 cd80b804 000000bb 01000000  ................
 0020 b9000000 00ba0500 0000cd80 b8010000  ................
 0030 00bb0000 0000cd80                    ........
```

```
$ objdump --full-contents bad.o

bad.o:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .text:
 0000 b8030000 00bb0200 0000b900 000000ba  ................
 0010 05000000 cd80b804 000000bb 01000000  ................
 0020 b9000000 00ba0500 0000cd80 b8010000  ................
 0030 00bb0000 0000cd80                    ........
```

^ They’re identical, but for the .data section.

```
$ readelf -e good.out

ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8049000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          8460 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         7
  Section header string table index: 6

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08049000 001000 000038 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        0804a000 002000 000001 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          0804a004 002001 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 002004 0000b0 10      5   7  4
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0020b4 000029 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0020dd 00002c 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00094 0x00094 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x08049000 0x08049000 0x00038 0x00038 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0804a000 0x0804a000 0x00001 0x0000c RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .text 
   02     .data .bss
```

```
$ readelf -e bad.out

ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8049000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4372 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 5

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08049000 001000 000038 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .bss              NOBITS          0804a000 002000 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 001038 000090 10      4   5  4
  [ 4] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0010c8 000025 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0010ed 000026 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00094 0x00094 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x08049000 0x08049000 0x00038 0x00038 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0804a000 0x0804a000 0x00000 0x00008 RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .text 
   02     .bss
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `file a.out` where `a.out` is the binary produced by this code?  Also, what OS are you programming for?

Comment: Why can't you use `gdb`? Maybe solve that issue first. As a workaround, enable core dumps and study that elsewhere. Or look in syslog, that can tell you the crash location as well.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that change would matter.  Unless I missed something, vitsoft's guess that you used the wrong build options for the non-working version seems most likely to me.  Despite your good effort to document exactly what you did, this isn't a [mcve], at least not reproducible on normal Linux systems.  But note that `ld echo.asm` definitely isn't right: `ld` wants a `.o` as input, not NASM source text.  Probably you need `ld -melf_i386 echo.o` unless you have a 32-bit install of Linux.

Comment: `readelf -e a.out` might reveal something, as well as `objdump --full-contents a.out`.

Comment: @PeterCordes `ld echo.asm` was a mistake in my posting. I know that I could never link an ASCII text file. I don't have another 32-bit Linux system to test this on, so I can't test whether it's reproducible.

Comment: You can do `ld -m elf_i386 echo.o` to do the same thing on an x86-64 Linux system.  It works fine for me on mine, as expected.  Try `strace ./a.out` on your not-working binary to see what system calls it makes, and use `gdb ./a.out` to see where it segfaults, if you can still repro this.  (Are you sure you didn't run an old file that wasn't built from the right source?)

Comment: The `man` entry for `ld -m` is "Don't treat multiple definitions as an error.  This is no longer supported. This option is obsolete." and when running `ld -m elf_i386 echo.o`, I get `option -m is obsolete and being ignored`. It would appear we have different versions of `ld`?

Comment: Look in syslog, it might have something like _"a.out[11187]: segfault at 0 ip 000056534d788660 sp 00007ffdcc224fe8 error 6 in a.out"_

Comment: There is no log on Alpine Linux, apparently.

Comment: If you put `jmp $` as the first instrutction after `_start`, does it still segfault?  If not, then what does `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` display while the program is running?  Also, what are your versions of `ld` and of the kernel?  Are you running this on a native machine, vm, docker container, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out changing `.bss` to `.data` solved the issue.

That means the start of the program looks like this:

```
section .data
  in: resb 5
    
section .text
  global _start
...
```

This makes no sense to me, and produces a warning when assembling:

```
$ nasm -f elf32 echo.asm
echo.asm:2: warning: uninitialized space declared in non-BSS section `.data': zeroing [-w+zeroing]
```

Of course, `.data` is the wrong section to place uninitialized data in, but that’s the only way that works.

**EDIT**: I know now that this question was really not answerable without knowing my system. I’m using [iSH](https://ish.app), a userspace Alpine Linux emulator. Since this is not a typical system, the issue likely lies in the emulator. I has assumed the issue was in my assembly.

Comment: That makes no sense, this should work in `.bss`, and does on normal systems.  What `nasm` and `ld` versions do you have installed?  And Linux kernel version?  IDK if there was ever a bug in ld or the kernel for executables with no `.data` section (or a zero-size one) that made them mis-handle a `.bss`.  (Or I guess mis-handle the .text section, since a messed up BSS would just make the read/write system calls return `-EFAULT` and then still exit cleanly.)

Answer (score 0):

I saved your source as "good.asm" and then the modified source with `section .data` removed as "bad.asm" and then assembled, linked and run both variants without any issues:

```
dohled@vm23726:~$ uname -a
Linux vm23726 4.4.0-177-generic #207-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 16 01:16:10 UTC 2020 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
dohled@vm23726:~$ cat bad.asm
section .bss
  in: resb 5

section .text
  global _start

_start:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 2
  mov ecx, in
  mov edx, 5
  int 0x80

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, in
  mov edx, 5
  int 0x80

  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80
dohled@vm23726:~$ nasm good.asm -f elf
dohled@vm23726:~$ nasm bad.asm -f elf
dohled@vm23726:~$ ld good.o -o good.exe -m elf_i386
dohled@vm23726:~$ ld bad.o -o bad.exe -m elf_i386
dohled@vm23726:~$ ./good.exe
1234
1234
dohled@vm23726:~$ ./bad.exe
1234
1234
dohled@vm23726:~$ readelf -e good.exe
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8048080
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          452 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         7
  Section header string table index: 4

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048080 000080 000038 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        080490b8 0000b8 000001 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          080490bc 0000b9 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 4] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000195 00002c 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0000bc 0000b0 10      6   7  4
  [ 6] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00016c 000029 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x000b8 0x000b8 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000b8 0x080490b8 0x080490b8 0x00001 0x0000c RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text
   01     .data .bss

dohled@vm23726:~$ readelf -e bad.exe
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8048080
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          404 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 3

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048080 000080 000038 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .bss              NOBITS          080490b8 0000b8 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00016c 000026 00      0   0  1
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0000b8 000090 10      5   5  4
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000148 000024 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x000b8 0x000b8 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000b8 0x080490b8 0x080490b8 0x00000 0x00008 RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text
   01     .bss
dohled@vm23726:~$
```

As you can see, "bad.exe" works as expected without segfault. You have probably built your program with wrong tools settings.
When you link a 32bit Linux executable (wich is signalized by using `INT 0x80` instead of `SYSCALL`), the GNU linker `ld` has to be informed about it by the option `-m elf_i386`.

Comment: Since `nasm` created a 32 bit ELF, the linker is presumably 32 bit since without that it would generate an error and not produce an executable. So, `-m elf_i386` won't solve the problem.

Comment: @vitsoft - on a system with 32-bit user-space, `ld`'s default is `-m elf_i386`.  Unless the question is wrong about what options they used, that must be what the querent has.

Comment: Adding that option has no effect on the output, so I’m assuming it’s the default on my system.